# Simple MLE solution from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, least-squares, mle

So am trying to fit a linear least squares model on MATLAB for a custom function. My data, called `logprice_hour_seas`, looks like a complicated nonlinear function, which I want to fit using my custom function called `seasonMatrix` but to understand how MATLAB's MLE works I do this dumb fit saying seasonMatrix is simply a linear function. Help me understand this code, which I copied from MATLAB's site, and the logic (read below)

```
Times = [0:1/8760:8712/8760];
% Calibrate parameters for the seasonality model
seasonMatrix = @(t) [t];
C = seasonMatrix(Times);
seasonParam = C\logprice_hour_seas;
```

Now I should have some error in my model (a lot of it!). But I do `logprice_hour_seas-C*seasonParam`, and this is all zeros! Well, MLE was solved using `logprice_hour_seas=C*seasonParam` so this is not surprising. What do I not understand??

Comment: You lack information. You do not need to have error, some models can perfectly fit the data, it just depends in the data. did you just said that you create the data `logprice_hour_seas` using the same data? I mean, if you create data using a model, and then solve it, you get the data, obviously, right? There is no noise. Are you committing [the inverse crime](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0401050)?

Comment: @AnderBiguri No the model I use does not fit the data. Infact, this same issue happens if I choose any another model. I did not create the data.

Comment: You need to show us a complete example then

Comment: @AnderBiguri As I said, any fictitious data would work. But if you insist, try this:
logprice_hour_seas=[5.2560    5.2151    5.2324    5.2224    5.2292];
PriceTimes = [0:1/8760:4/8760];
seasonMatrix = @(t) [sin(2.*pi.*t) cos(2.*pi.*t) sin(4.*pi.*t) ...
    cos(4.*pi.*t) t ones(size(t, 1), 1)];
C = seasonMatrix(PriceTimes);
seasonParam = C\logprice_hour_seas;

Comment: Are you sure you are building your matrices correctly? In your example `C` is a row vector and `logprice_hour_seas` is a column vector. Thus the result `seasonParam` has a value for each of the combinations. you get zero errors because `seasonParam` sets everything to zero but the one corresponding to `seasonMatrix==1`, thus values multiplied by 1 equal values, with zero error. TDLR: you are messing up the matrix sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you are messing up matrix sizes.

The way you create your values `seasonParam` becomes `5x26` matrix. and `C` a `1x26` matrix. You are simulating a under-determined system of equations, that can have multiple solutions.

In this case, fortunately for the algorithm, some of the values of `C` are 1 ! That means that of all 26 `5x1` vectors in the solution (`seasonParam`) only the ones multiplied by 1 need to be set up as the result value (`logprice_hour_seas`) to have a perfect fit! Thus, your solution `seasonParam` is

```
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
5.2560    5.2151    5.2324    5.2224    5.2292
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
 0         0         0         0         0
```

The whole model makes no sense, so I am assuming you are just messing up the dimensions.
Try the following:

```
 logprice_hour_seas=[5.2560 5.2151 5.2324 5.2224 5.2292]'; 
 PriceTimes = [0:1/8760:4/8760]'; 
 seasonMatrix = @(t) [sin(2.*pi.*t) cos(2.*pi.*t) sin(4.*pi.*t)  cos(4.*pi.*t) t ones(size(t, 1), 1)];
 C = seasonMatrix(PriceTimes);
 seasonParam = C\logprice_hour_seas;
```

Comment: Yes, the dimensions were transposed. Thanks.